# Filtrar elementos de un Queue

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, queue

Estaba practicando un poco de Javascript, hice un par de funciones básicas y luego quería aplicar varios tipos de filtros, logre aplicar varios, pero luego me trabe con el que supongo será el mas sencillo pero no lo puedo terminar de lograr.
Lo que quería aplicar en el ultimo filtro es que por ejemplo si al final llegan varias personas con el mismo nombre o apellido que solo retorne el 1ro de el array.
Se que haciendo un map por ejemplo puedo separar con "item[0]" el 1er nombre pero probé con includes o match y no funciona de la forma indicada.
Si alguien me podría dar una solución se lo agradeciera

```js
function Queue () {
    this.data = [];
}

Queue.prototype.add = function (data) {
    this.data.push(data);
}

Queue.prototype.addxindex = function (data, index) {
if (index < 0 || index > this.size() || !index) {
    throw new TypeError ("El index esta mal mamon")
}
    this.data.splice(index, 0, data);
}

Queue.prototype.removefirst = function () {
    this.data.shift();
}

Queue.prototype.size = function () {
    return this.data.length;
}

Queue.prototype.removelast = function () {
    this.data.pop();
}

Queue.prototype.print = function () {
    return this.data;
}

Queue.prototype.addfirst = function(data) {
    this.data.unshift(data)
}

Queue.prototype.removeIndex = function(index) {
if (index < 0 || index > this.size() || !index){
    throw new TypeError ("El index esta mal mamon");
}
else {
    this.data.splice(index-1, 1);
}
}

Queue.prototype.search = function (data) {
var test = [];
var index = 0;
var aux = [];
var result = this.data.filter(valor => valor.age > 18 && valor.Job === data);
result = result.filter((valor, index) => result.findIndex(Obj => Obj.fullname.Position === valor.fullname.Position) === index)
result = result.map(item => item.fullname.Name);
result = result.map(function (item, position) {
    item = item.split(" ");
    return item 
})
result.forEach(function (element) {
    test[element[0]] ? test[element[0]]++ : test[element[0]] = 1
})
return test;
}

var test = new Queue;

test.add({Job: "Junior", age: 33 ,fullname :{Name: "Pedro Lopez", Position: 3}});
test.add({Job: "Junior", age: 33 ,fullname :{Name: "Pedro Daldo", Position: 3}})
test.add({Job: "Senior", age: 44 ,fullname :{Name: "John Kick", Position: 3}})
test.add({Job: "Senior", age: 17 ,fullname :{Name: "Lucas Popus", Position: 2}})
test.addxindex({Job: "SemiSenior", age : 13,fullname: {Name : "Pablo Try", Position: 2}}, 3)
test.addfirst({Job: "Junior", age: 22, fullname :{Name : "Pedro Popo", Position: 4}})
test.addfirst({Job: "Junior", age: 25, fullname :{Name : "Pedro Pipi", Position: 6}})
test.addfirst({Job: "Junior", age: 25, fullname :{Name : "Juja Lag", Position: 8}})
test.removeIndex(6)
console.log(test.search("Junior"))
console.log(test.print())
console.log(test.size())
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo más sencillo seria utilizar [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find):

```js
const data = JSON.parse(`[{
    "Job": "Junior",
    "age": 25,
    "fullname": {
      "Name": "Juja Lag",
      "Position": 8
    }
  },
  {
    "Job": "Junior",
    "age": 25,
    "fullname": {
      "Name": "Pedro Pipi",
      "Position": 6
    }
  },
  {
    "Job": "Junior",
    "age": 22,
    "fullname": {
      "Name": "Pedro Popo",
      "Position": 4
    }
  },
  {
    "Job": "Junior",
    "age": 33,
    "fullname": {
      "Name": "Pedro Lopez",
      "Position": 3
    }
  },
  {
    "Job": "Junior",
    "age": 33,
    "fullname": {
      "Name": "Pedro Daldo",
      "Position": 3
    }
  },
  {
    "Job": "SemiSenior",
    "age": 13,
    "fullname": {
      "Name": "Pablo Try",
      "Position": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "Job": "Senior",
    "age": 17,
    "fullname": {
      "Name": "Lucas Popus",
      "Position": 2
    }
  }
]`);

function obtenerPrimero(propiedad, valor) {
  console.log(data.find((persona) => (persona[propiedad] === valor)));
}

obtenerPrimero("Job", "Junior");
obtenerPrimero("age", 25);
```

Answer (score 2):

El método [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find) devuelve solo la primera coincidencia y puedes agregar métodos de búsqueda por nombre (o por lo que quieras) al prototipo.

```js
function Queue () {
    this.data = [];
}

Queue.prototype.add = function (data) {
    this.data.push(data);
}

Queue.prototype.addxindex = function (data, index) {
if (index < 0 || index > this.size() || !index) {
    throw new TypeError ("El index esta mal mamon")
}
    this.data.splice(index, 0, data);
}

Queue.prototype.removefirst = function () {
    this.data.shift();
}

Queue.prototype.size = function () {
    return this.data.length;
}

Queue.prototype.removelast = function () {
    this.data.pop();
}

Queue.prototype.print = function () {
    return this.data;
}

Queue.prototype.addfirst = function(data) {
    this.data.unshift(data)
}

Queue.prototype.removeIndex = function(index) {
if (index < 0 || index > this.size() || !index){
    throw new TypeError ("El index esta mal mamon");
}
else {
    this.data.splice(index-1, 1);
}
}

Queue.prototype.search = function (data) {
var test = [];
var index = 0;
var aux = [];
var result = this.data.filter(valor => valor.age > 18 && valor.Job === data);
result = result.filter((valor, index) => result.findIndex(Obj => Obj.fullname.Position === valor.fullname.Position) === index)
result = result.map(item => item.fullname.Name);
result = result.map(function (item, position) {
    item = item.split(" ");
    return item 
})
result.forEach(function (element) {
    test[element[0]] ? test[element[0]]++ : test[element[0]] = 1
})
return test;
}
// Buscar por nombre, sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas
Queue.prototype.searchByName = function (name) {
    return this.data.find(item => item.fullname.Name.indexOf(name) >= 0);
}
// Buscar por nombre, insensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas
Queue.prototype.searchByNameI = function (name) {
    // Comparar valores convertidos a minúsculas
    return this.data.find(item => item.fullname.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) >= 0);
}

var test = new Queue;

test.add({Job: "Junior", age: 33 ,fullname :{Name: "Pedro Lopez", Position: 3}});
test.add({Job: "Junior", age: 33 ,fullname :{Name: "Pedro Daldo", Position: 3}})
test.add({Job: "Senior", age: 44 ,fullname :{Name: "John Kick", Position: 3}})
test.add({Job: "Senior", age: 17 ,fullname :{Name: "Lucas Popus", Position: 2}})
test.addxindex({Job: "SemiSenior", age : 13,fullname: {Name : "Pablo Try", Position: 2}}, 3)
test.addfirst({Job: "Junior", age: 22, fullname :{Name : "Pedro Popo", Position: 4}})
test.addfirst({Job: "Junior", age: 25, fullname :{Name : "Pedro Pipi", Position: 6}})
test.addfirst({Job: "Junior", age: 25, fullname :{Name : "Juja Lag", Position: 8}})
test.removeIndex(6)
console.log(test.search("Junior"))
console.log(test.print())
console.log(test.size())
console.log(test.searchByName('Pedro'))
console.log(test.searchByName('Try'))
console.log(test.searchByNameI('lucas'))
console.log(test.searchByNameI('asd')) // undefined, no se encontró coincidencia
```